# Buffer large file content to Flask frontend

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm currently trying to figure out how to approach a problem making large files accessible to end users, using Flask as the engine for the frontend.

To better explain, here is what I have to do (and did):

1. [Done] Ingest data out of several files (logs) that take around 200mb/file.
2. [Done] Transform and apply some filters.
3. [Done] Store each (log) file in it's variable with everything done in step 2.
4. Make the data available to end users of the frontend, without needing SSH + tail -f for each session of the frontend.

My issue is understanding what tools I have at my disposal to show the data in a Flask template, taking into account, that the data might change (append to the list of already saved logs in step 3).

Basic explanation: I try to read live data out of some files and make it accessible to any frontend user, without creating an "ssh  -c tail -f logfile.log" for each session of the frontend.